# How to make JQuery accessible for classic JavaScript files if I'm using gulp and browserify

Tags: javascript, jquery, npm, gulp, browserify

We decided to manage our JS dependencies via `npm`, and I'm trying to create single file `bundle.js` by concatenating different JS libraries:

```
const vendors = [
    'jquery',
    'jquery-ui',
    'react',
    'react-dom',
    'highlight.js',
    'jquery-mousewheel',
    'select2',
    'moment-timezone',
];

const destination = {
    js: './static/assets/js'
};

gulp.task('build:vendor', () => {
    const browserify = Browserify({
        insertGlobals: true,
        debug: true
    });

    vendors.forEach(lib => {
        browserify.require(lib);
    });

    browserify.transform('browserify-shim', {global: true}).bundle()
        .pipe(source('vendor.js'))
        .pipe(buffer())
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(destination.js));
});
```

As the result, `bundle.js` file created in proper location and I'm including it as usual at my HTML page:

```
...
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/assets/js/vendor.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/ui.js' %}"></script>
...
```

In the `ui.js`, I'm trying to execute standart JS code:

```
$(function() {
    alert('Foo');
});
```

And getting error in my browser's console:

`$ is not defined`

My `package.json` contains this, but I'm not sure if these configurations are required:

```
"browser": {
    "jquery": "./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js"
  },
  "browserify": {
    "transform": [
      "browserify-shim"
    ]
  },
  "browserify-shim": {
    "jquery": "global:$"
  }
```

What am I doing wrong?
I've already tried `browserify-shim` but without any result.